# MySql Case inside a function

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to achieve something like below, but I'm going all wrong - with the logic, the syntax an all else. Can you please help me?

I'm trying to `SET STATIC =` based on certain conditions. If this were `PHP`, I'd have used `Break`. I came this far, but nothing works. Can you see how to do this?

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `caseTest`(`n` INT)
    RETURNS varchar(512)
    LANGUAGE SQL
    DETERMINISTIC
    CONTAINS SQL
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
    COMMENT ''
BEGIN

  DECLARE x VARCHAR(1500); 
  DECLARE y VARCHAR(1500); 
  DECLARE static VARCHAR(1500); 

  CASE n
        WHEN '14' THEN SET x = 'Place Order Link';
        WHEN '01' THEN SET x = 'Cancel Order Link';
        WHEN '11' THEN SET x = 'Order Cancelled - Place order link';
        SET static = concat(<a href="">,x,</a>);

        WHEN '00' THEN SET x = 'Order - Under Process'; #No link here
        WHEN '10' THEN SET x = 'Cancel - Under Process'; #No link here
        SET static = x;

        ELSE SET static = 'Error generating link';
    END;

 set y = 'Flag Link ~ Edit Link ~ Move Link';

  RETURN concat(x,y);
END
```

Answer (score 3):

You want to move the `set` outside the `case` statement:

```
  set x = case n 
        WHEN '14' THEN 'Place Order Link';
        WHEN '01' THEN 'Cancel Order Link';
        WHEN '11' THEN 'Order Cancelled - Place order link';
        WHEN '00' THEN 'Order - Under Process'; #No link here
        WHEN '10' THEN 'Cancel - Under Process'; #No link here
      end;
  set static = (case when n in ('14', '01', '11') then concat(<a href="">,x,</a>)
                     when n in ('00', '10') then x
                     ELSE 'Error generating link'
                end);
```

You can also do this with `if`.  The `set` with `case` seems closer to your original logic.

I see no reason why the above should not work (except for possible syntax errors).  You can try the `if` version:

```
 if n = '14' THEN x = 'Place Order Link';
 elseif n = '01' THEN x = 'Cancel Order Link';
 elseif n = '11' THEN x = 'Order Cancelled - Place order link';
 elseif n = '00' THEN x = 'Order - Under Process'; #No link here
 elseif n = '10' THEN x = 'Cancel - Under Process'; #No link here

 if n in ('14', '01', '11') then static = concat(<a href="">,x,</a>);
 elseif n in ('00', '10') then static = x;
 ELSE static = 'Error generating link';
```

Comment: Does MySql syntax vary based on the OS? I'm on WAMP and I'm a tuff time getting this to save. I'm using Heidi Sql.